# javascript cant get string from textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, user-controls

i am trying to get date string from Textbox ASP.NET control but with no success.
my code is:

```
function countdown() {
    now = new Date();
    var biddate = $("#InitiateDate1").val();
    kickoff = Date.parse(biddate);
    diff = kickoff - now;...
```

Comment: Can you show html for your textbox?

Comment: Look at your HTML source.. I bet the id of the textbox is NOT InitiateDate1. Because your doing correct by calling .val()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's `$('<%=InitiateDate1.ClientID%>').val();`

Comment: i tried to change to: `$('<%=InitiateDate1.ClientID%>').val();` with no success. my control is : `<asp:TextBox ID="InitiateDate1" runat="server" Text="02/07/2011">02/07/2011</asp:TextBox>`. when i replace `$("#InitiateDate1").val();` with "02/07/2011" it works perfectly.

Comment: Please provide more code. Otherwise it's very hard to help you.

Comment: this is the code and the control.from debuging i can see that i have empty string in biddate.

Comment: sorry but i forgot to mention that i am using master page:)

Comment: i checked it with no master page and the result is the same.nothing..plase help

Comment: @walter why you have text between <asp:texbox...>and </asp:TextBox>. If you have all ready set the text property of the textbox?

Comment: thanks all.the solution was to add `ClientIDMode="Static"` property to my textbox.

Answer (score 0):

just try

```
function countdown() {
    now = new Date();
    var biddate = document.getElementById('<%=InitiateDate1.ClientID%>').value
    kickoff = Date.parse(biddate);
```